# Getting list of published topics from within C++ code

Tags: roscpp, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the vicon_bridge node, which publishes a topic "vicon/<subject_name>/<segment_name>" for every subject and segment it finds. In this example, consider that it publishes the topics:

vicon/subject1/segment1
vicon/subject2/segment1

Is there a way, from within C++ code, to get a list of all "vicon/*" topics that are being published? Something like 'rostopic list' that can be used from within the code and can search on a topic "subdirectory"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206893/getting-list-of-published-topics-from-within-c++-code/) by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-04-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could

```
#include <ros/master.h>
```

and call

```
  ros::master::V_TopicInfo topic_infos;
  ros::master::getTopics(topic_infos);
```

This gets you topic infos (topic name and data type as std::strings) of all advertised topics; obviously not just those in vicon/ but you can filter them with boost:regex or e. g. split and check like:

```
  std::vector<std::string> lv_elems;
  
  char lc_delim[2];
  lc_delim[0] = '/';
  lc_delim[1] = '\0';
  
  boost::algorithm::split( lv_elems, topic_infos[0].name, boost::algorithm::is_any_of( lc_delim ) );
  
  if ( lv_elems[0] == "vicon" )
{
   // topic of topic_infos[0] is really in namespace vicon!!
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5